# How do I swagger generate Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate `kotlin` code from a swagger json file, and I can't figure out the command-line parameters that should be used.

I've tried Swagger codegen `v2.3.1` and `v2.2.3` and both fail for `kotlin`, `kotlin-client`, and `kotlin-server` with the same error. What's the correct switch to generate Kotlin?

Update from Helen's question: I installed swagger codegen with:

```
git clone git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git ./swagger-codegen
cd swagger-codegen
git checkout tags/v2.2.3
```

I also tested with Swagger codegen's `bin/kotlin-client-petstore.sh` and `kotlin` was not recognized for that script.

(I've also tried the [Swagger Codegen plugin for IntelliJ](https://github.com/jimschubert/intellij-swagger-codegen/) because it does list `kotlin` as an output target, but it does not correctly process the swagger json.)

Here's the command-line pattern I'm using, which works for `typescript-node`:

```
java -jar ./swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i sample.json -l typescript-node -o typescript_node_sdk
```

However, it fails for `kotlin`, `kotlin-client`, `kotlin-server`:

```
$ java -jar ./swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i sample.json -l kotlin -o kotlin_sdk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load config class with name kotlin Available: android
aspnet5
async-scala
csharp
dart
flash
python-flask
go
java
jaxrs
jaxrs-cxf
jaxrs-resteasy
inflector
javascript
javascript-closure-angular
jmeter
nodejs-server
objc
perl
php
python
qt5cpp
ruby
scala
scalatra
silex-PHP
sinatra
slim
spring-mvc
dynamic-html
html
swagger
swagger-yaml
swift
tizen
typescript-angular
typescript-node
akka-scala
CsharpDotNet2
clojure
haskell-servant

at io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:31)
at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:346)
at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:221)
at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:29)
... 3 more
```

Comment: The language id is `kotlin`, it's a client generator. How did you install the Swagger Codegen? Are you sure you are using Codegen v. 2.2.3+?

Comment: I'm sure of the Swagger Codegen versions. I will look at other ways to install it that may eliminate this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Helen's question, I looked at [Swagger Codegen Building](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#building) and

```
mvn clean package
```

made `kotlin` appear as a recognized switch.

Comment: FWIW, I've been developing a new SDK code generator on behalf of my employer that generates Kotlin and a couple other languages (so far). https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-codegen is the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [openapi generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate the code in kotlin using:

```
openapi-generator generate -i petstore.yml -g kotlin  --config api-config.json
```

openapi generator is a fork of the swagger codegen and offers the same kind of functionalities. Find the kotlin generators specs in [the documentation](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/kotlin.md).

Comment: Thanks. At the time I asked this, openapi-generator didn't exist. I now use Looker's [code generator](https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-codegen) instead that works with both Swagger and OpenAPI specifications (I'm primary author on it, currently).  Disclaimer: it works on our specs. Untested with others.

Comment: @JohnKaster how is Looker's solution better than swagger's and aren't swagger and openAPI the same? I'm looking for a codegen for an Android/Kotlin proyect and v3 openapi

Comment: @Sylhare I'm still not able to use the generated code, there is so much files being generated that I'm so confused, there is a manifest, settings.gradle, etc. soooo many files, I suppose most of the people only expect the classes, I'm really having a hard time trying to figure out how to use the generated files, which ones to keep, where to put them, etc.

Comment: If you have a gradle project and you need to generate the classes, you can use the [openapi gradle plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin) only to generate the classes you need. Here it would be more to generate an entire kotlin project from a swagger/openapi file (hence the gradle files and all).

Comment: @David yes, OpenAPI 3x is a rename from Swagger 3.x. The solution our team has built is definitely better for our purposes, but your needs may not be the same. In anticipation of this question, a few years ago I wrote this [rationale](https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-codegen/blob/main/docs/rationale.md) doc to explain our position. With our generator design (we'd like to iterate cleaner) a new language SDK can be produced in < 3 days as explained in [BYO SDK](https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-codegen/blob/main/docs/byosdk.md). I make no warranties for others.

Comment: One thing we haven't yet done is full spec-based authentication, although we do have an authentication interface to support alternative API/SDK auth flows.